# Applying drawer on all activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, navigation-drawer, material-design

I'm trying to use [mikepenz material drawer on github](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) . My question is how to go to other activity from the existing activity & also applied the navigation drawer to it? I have tried to use this `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), try2.class);
                startActivity(intent);` 
but it does not works. I want to navigate the existing activity to a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Navigation-Drawer on all activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678151/android-navigation-drawer-on-all-activities)

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to create a BaseActivity that implements the drawer.
And let all your activities implements BaseActivity.