# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have to set the same navigation drawer in three activity.So for code reduction,I had used BaseActivity.

I have got the error inflating class android.widget.ListView.

**Stacktrace:**

```
09-10 02:03:13.988  14284-14284/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.steve.database/com.steve.database.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.steve.database.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:72)
            at com.steve.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.steve.database.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:72)
            at com.steve.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0000 a=-1 r=0x7f0b0000}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2063)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:459)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:235)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:766)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:144)
            at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:140)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.steve.database.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:72)
            at com.steve.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have pointed out the error line in below code:

**BaseActivity.java:**

```
 private ListView mDrawerList;
  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ArrayList<Chapter> chapterArray;
  ChapterListAdapter adapter;
  SqliteDbHelper dbHelper;


  dbHelper = new SqliteDbHelper(this);

  dbHelper.openDataBase();

  LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

  View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null); ---->Error line

  mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_menu);

  chapterArray=new ArrayList<Chapter>();
  chapterArray=dbHelper.getChapterDetails();

  adapter = new ChapterListAdapter(this,chapterArray);
  mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**custom_actionbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#5467F7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Chapters"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    SqliteDbHelper dbHelper;
    Chapter chapter;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Chapter> al;
    ChapterListAdapter cla;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       al=dbHelper.getChapterDetails();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
        cla=new ChapterListAdapter(MainActivity.this,al);

        lv.setAdapter(cla);
       }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: check the background of list view in navigation drawer...clearly mentioned in logcat report -- caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0000 a=-1 r=0x7f0b0000}

Comment: @ShadowDroid I had set directly #E36666.But it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: hey, try to remove this line..
`android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: @sourabhbans done that but still showing the same error.

Comment: can you give a try to it..
`mDrawerList = (ListView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.list_menu);`

Comment: @sourabhbans already i had tried that.it wasn't worked for me.

Comment: why are you inflating the view,not  `setContentView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);`

Comment: you can see here one of my answer in same issue.. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/31218714/3790052](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31218714/3790052)

Comment: @sourabhbans because I am using baseactivity.thats why default to add the drawer to three classes.Anyway let me try and tell you.

Comment: i have done that kind of work before..I have set a single navigation drawer for all my app's activities.

Comment: do not know you came across this solution or not but please try it once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922641/sliding-drawer-appear-in-all-activities