# How to navigate through activites using a NavigationView?

Tags: android

Is there a way in which I can create a single `NavigationView` (with its elements) and call other custom activites while maintaining the same `NavigationView` for all of them?

I did as @johnrao07 said and created an `Activity` that will work as a `BaseActivity` for all my activities. It looks like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

HealthFileSQLiteOpenHelper healthFileHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
        finish();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {
        finish();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Then I have a custom `Activity` that I want it to extend from `BaseActivity`:

```
public class ProfilesActivity extends BaseActivity  {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TROUBLE HERE
    setContentView(R.layout.profiles_content);
}
```

I want this `Activity` to have its own content, and I want the `NavigationView` to be showed at any Activity that extends from BaseActivity...

With no luck...

This is my xml:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.testnavigation2.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- <include layout="@layout/profiles_content" /> -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- Put what you want as your normal screen in here, you can also choose for a linear layout or any other layout, whatever you prefer -->
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I still can't see the NavigationView at each Activity (with this method I lost it completely from my screen).

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your other **Activities** should extend The **MainActivity** which contains the **navigationView** .

Comment: Not working... If I extend the MainActivity it doesn't keep the NavigationView and anything...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451715/same-navigation-drawer-in-different-activities   ,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678151/android-navigation-drawer-on-all-activities

Comment: Ok, I think it's working now. I inflated contend and it seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Your `app_bar_main.xml` file add `NavigationView`, and you have to do the same for all of your activity layouts where you want to have `NavigationView` . Your `app_bar_main.xml` should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">    

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.testnavigation2.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:elevation="0dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- <include layout="@layout/profiles_content" /> -->

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<!-- Put what you want as your normal screen in here, you can also choose for a linear layout or any other layout, whatever you prefer -->
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@android:color/white"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```