# Navigation Drawer for multiple Activities not working on item click

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer

Hey Guys I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678151/android-navigation-drawer-on-all-activities) thread a while ago and tried to replicate it since i'm using multiple activities within my app. 
I copied all my code for the navigation drawer within my new `NavigationDrawerActivity.java` which looks like this:

```html
package info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.CameraFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.ExposeDetailFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.MyAccountFragment;
import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.SettingsFragment;

public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public NavigationView navigationView;
    public DrawerLayout drawer;
    public View navHeader;
    public TextView txtName;
    public TextView txtWebsite;
    public Toolbar toolbar;

    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    public static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
    public static final String TAG_CAMERA = "camera";
    public static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
    public static final String TAG_MY_ACCOUNT = "myaccoount";
    public static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    public String[] activityTitles;

    // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
    public boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    public Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer,null);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,drawerLayout,true);
        super.setContentView(drawerLayout);

        //DrawerContent here
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Navigation view header
        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.webseite);

        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();


    }


    /***
     * Load navigation menu header information
     * like background image, profile image
     * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
     */
    private void loadNavHeader() {
        // name, website
        txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
        txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");


    }

    /***
     * Returns respected fragment that user
     * selected from navigation menu
     */
    public void loadHomeFragment() {
        // selecting appropriate nav menu item
        selectNavMenu();

        // set toolbar title
        setToolbarTitle();

        // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
        // just close the navigation drawer
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();


            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        // This effect can be seen in GMail app
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Click action
                Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, NewExposeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ein neues Exposé erstellen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/


        //Closing drawer on item click
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // refresh toolbar menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public Fragment getHomeFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                // home
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                // expose List
                HomeFragment homeFragment1 = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment1;
            case 2:
                //Camera fragment
                CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
                return cameraFragment;
            case 3:
                // notifications fragment
                MyAccountFragment myAccountFragment = new MyAccountFragment();
                return myAccountFragment;
            case 4:

                // settings fragment
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }

    public void setToolbarTitle() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
    }

    public void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }

    public void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_camera:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_CAMERA;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_movies:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_my_account:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MY_ACCOUNT;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_rss:
                        startActivity( new Intent(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, RSSFeedActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_login:
                        startActivity( new Intent(NavigationDrawerActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }

        // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
        // when user is in other fragment than home
        if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
            // checking if user is on other navigation menu
            // rather than home
            if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                loadHomeFragment();
                return;
            }
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return  true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.add_expose) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ein neues Exposé soll erstellt werden!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





}
```

and here the `activity_navigation_drawer.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >


</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here is the `activity_navigation_drawer.xml` which is `menu` Ressource file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_list_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_photos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_movies"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_movies" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_my_account"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:title="Mein Account" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Other">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_rss"
                android:title="News"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_rss_feed_black_24dp" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_login"
                android:title="@string/action_logout"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lock_black_24dp" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

It's working great up to the fact that when i click an item in the navigation nothing happens. Are there any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong.

You can find the whole project [here](https://github.com/RBlischk/NavigationDrawer).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: nothing happens because you have not coded what should happen. you are starting activity for only `R.id.nav_rss` and `R.id.nav_login`

Comment: @Saurabh so you are saying that i need to put the first 4 into activities as well and not use fragments? i'm kinda confused now

Answer (score 0):

First , post a reference or code to how you are creating the menu item , do u create it in the resources menu file or simply load an array , If you are using array then i would suggest you to use menu xml to create menu items.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

also make corresponding changes in ur code,check 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: i added the code snippet. it is an menu ressource file that adds the menu